# Issues with flex wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am taking a web design class so I am still learning a lot and am running into a few issues with a project. In the project we are supposed to create a webpage about ourselves. I have two flex columns and I am trying to get it where the picture stays the same width with the about section on the right filling up any available space. When the window is too small the about section should move beneath it. Right now the about section just stays beneath it.

I have played around with the flex property and previously had the content beside as I initially wanted but after adjusting multiple things to keep the about section a minimum width, it is no longer initially beside the picture.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: recharge;
  src: url(../fonts/recharge.woff2);
  src: url(../fonts/recharge.woff);
  src: url(../fonts/recharge.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: sofachrome;
  src: url(../fonts/sofachrome.woff2);
  src: url(../fonts/sofachrome.woff);
  src: url(../fonts/sofachrome.ttf);
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#site {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

#logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 12px;
}

header h1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 80px;
  font-family: sofachrome, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e80000, #7e0000);
  ;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #FFF);
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  font-family: recharge, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

nav li .active {
  color: #000;
}

nav li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #FFF);
}

#main {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 210px 200px 10px 200px;
}

#main h1 {
  font-family: recharge, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-left {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .25);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.column-right {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .25);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  min-width: 390px;
}

.column-right p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#profilepicture {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

footer {
  color: #E80000;
  font-family: recharge, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

footer h1 {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

footer a:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #FFF);
}

.contact {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="site">
  <header>
    <section id="banner">
      <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Ignite Logo">
      <h1>Austin Bates</h1>
    </section>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li><a href="military.html">Military History</a></li>
        <li><a href="3dmodeling.html">3D Modeling</a></li>
        <li><a href="cad.html">CAD Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="3dprinting.html">3D Printing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <img id="profilepicture" src="images/profilepicture.jpg" alt="Profile Picture">
      </div>
      <div class="column-right">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>My name is Austin, and I'm thrilled to share a bit about myself. At the moment, I am a 30-year-old Navy Submarine veteran residing in Orlando, Florida. I'm currently pursuing an Associates degree in Graphic and Interactive Design at Valencia College.
          Alongside my studies, I dedicate my time to working full-time with my brother and his wife, assisting them in their Amazon business. In addition to my professional endeavors, I manage my own Etsy side business specializing in components for
          constructing 3D printers. The world of 3D printing has become my passion, and I devote a significant amount of time to exploring and engaging in various projects related to it. Outside of my professional pursuits, I happily embrace my inner
          nerd. You can often find me engrossed in activities involving my 3D printers or indulging in my geeky interests. Among my favorite obsessions are Dragon Ball, Transformers, Star Wars, Demon Slayer, and Marvel (although I must admit, the recent
          Marvel content hasn't quite lived up to expectations). Although my life's journey has taken a different path than most, particularly at the age of 30, I wholeheartedly believe I am on the right track. I'm excited to witness where this unique
          path leads me and eagerly anticipate the opportunities it brings.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="email.html"><img class="contact" src="images/gmail.png" alt="Gmail"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="facebook"><img class="contact" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem (including images).